# How to solve T(n)=4T(sqrt(n/2))+n^(3/2)

Tags: time-complexity, complexity-theory

I want to solve a recurrence. A problem is divided in 4 subproblems. Each subproblem's size is square root of n/2. The solution of the 4 subproblems is combined with the function n^(3/2). I am looking for the time complexity.

[image: T(n)=4T(\sqrt{\frac{n}{2}})+n^{\frac{3}{2}}]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not really a programming problem, but a math or CS problem.

Comment: Also, this *sounds* like "here's my homework, do it for me". If you want to ask homework questions, they're better received if you show you worked on it yourself, and explain just where you are stumped despite your best effort.

Answer (score 0):

The time function is:

[image]

We can make this substitution:

[image]

And thus:

[image]

Now the `i + 1`th expansion of the time function gives a term:

[image]

And the termination index of `i`, assuming `T(0) = 0`:

[image]

And so the time complexity is given by:

[image]

Unfortunately, this is non-analytical (no elementary function representation).

Instead, however, we can make an extremely crude approximation which will almost certainly flabbergast every math-mo out there. Taking the terms at either end of the sum:

[image]

Assuming `m` is large, the first term is *much much* larger than the last. So we can make a lower bound on the series:

[image]

---

EDIT: Apologies, the sum starts from `i = 0`, including the last `2^(1.5*m)` term. BUT the time complexity bound is still the same. Also I should have used big-Omega notation not big-O...

Comment: Thank very much. I solved it using master theorem and i managed to find big - Θ (logn) but i am not sure.

Comment: @trachanas did you take into account the sqrt factor? cuz that makes things more complicated

Comment: @trachanas well I programmed it in C and plotted the runtime data in excel - it wasn't a log term, but seemed to be O(n^1.5) after all